# Call an extension method by data type

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to call an `extension` method like this

```
int.AnExtensionMethod()
```

Is this possible or I must an instance to call?

Comment: Why do you need to add extension methods to a _type_?

Comment: This isn't ruby. ;-)
(Where you can add methods to a class on the fly)

Comment: don't forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
 public static class intext {
        public static int doubleMe(this int x) {
            return 2 * x;
        }
    }
```

call it like this

```
  Console.WriteLine(5.doubleMe());
```

But I dont think that `int.doubleMe()` is not possible  you can read out this for more : [**Why No Extension Properties?**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx)

just to be more clear

`Console.WriteLine(5.doubleMe());`

is equivalent to

`Console.WriteLine(intext.doubleMe(5));`

**Extension method are used to extends the existing types not to add method in it.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it needs to be an instance of a class. I don't recall adding extension methods to classes themselves. 
Besides, why do you want to add an extension method to the `int` (or whatever) class?

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. So, you cannot do what you suggest above and it makes no sense to attempt to. Extension methods are METHODs. Methods act on instances of classes or objects...

See [this basic intro on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) and [this answer to a very simalar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/cc4fd6c2-7233-4921-a818-2196774e89c1/).

I hope this helps.